# Replace separator in dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has as separator `;` but I want `,` to be the new separator. I'm currently using `pandas.Dataframe.replace` to achieve it, but it seems like there is no effect.
The dataset is something like this:

```
A; B; C; D; E
1; 32; 234; 2; 23
2; 3; 1; 55; 545
3; 44; 12; 1; 3
...
```

Comment: What is reason for it? Do you need create `A-E` columns and `df = pd.read_csv(file)` failed? Then use `df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need turn the `regex` on

```
df = df.replace({';':','},regex=True)
```

Comment: Hard to know if it is correct answer (if data are in one column or not). So if answer should be changed from `df = df.replace({';':','},regex=True)` be free reopen answer, please.

Comment: How can I save this changes in my dataset permanently?

Comment: @yoyoyo after assign it is permanently ~ `df = df.replace({';':','},regex=True)
`